# Pivotal quantity and confidence interval

Tags: mathematical-statistics, confidence-interval, pivot

Let $X$  be a random variable with p.d.f.: $$f(X|\theta) = \frac{e^{x-\theta}}{(1+e^{x-\theta})^2}$$
where $-\infty<x<\infty$ and $-\infty<\theta<\infty$

Use the pivotal method to verify that if $0<\alpha_1<0.5$ and $0<\alpha_2<0.5$, then

$$\left[X-\log\left(\frac{1-\alpha_2}{\alpha_2}\right),X-\log\left(\frac{\alpha_1}{1+\alpha_1}\right)\right]$$ is a confidence interval for $\theta$ with coverage probability $1-(\alpha_1+\alpha_2)$
here my attempt
if I set $Y = X-\theta$
I get this $$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
F_Y(y) \equiv \mathbb{P}(Y \leqslant y) 
&= \mathbb{P}({X-\theta} \leqslant y) \\
&= \mathbb{P}(X \leqslant Y+\theta) \\
&= \int \limits_{-\infty}^{y-\theta} \frac{e^{x-\theta}}{(1+e^{x-\theta})^2} dx \\
&= \Bigg[ \frac{-1}{1+e^{x-\theta}} \Bigg]_{x=-\infty}^{x=y+\theta} \\
&= 1-\frac{1}{1+e^{y}}. \\
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$
from this I derived the pdf equal to $$f_Y(y) = \frac{e^y}{(1+e^y)^2}$$

from this I show that the distribution does not depend on the parameter anymore.
How can I demonstrate the confidence interval for $\theta$?

Comment: So you want $\mathbb{P}(c_{1}\leq \theta \leq c_{2}) = 1-a_{1}-a_{2}$ ?

Comment: oh yes, exactly

Comment: And the confidence interval I suppose is symmetric?? Because, the answer that I find is different than the one that you provided and I'm wondering I might doing some wrong calculations

Comment: why you think that the interval is symmetric?

Comment: Because I didn't know to what those $a_{1}$ and $a_{2}$ correspond.

Comment: But I think now I got the idea, check and tell me if it is what you epected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The good think with the pivotal method, is that you can actually find a distribution of the observations independent of the unknown parameter $\theta$ and the implicitly through that distribution construct the confidence interval for $\theta$.

So, so the goal is to create a $(1-a_{1}-a_{2})$ confidence interval for $\theta$ that will be

$$\mathbb{P}(c_{1}\leq \theta \leq c_{2})=1-a_{1}-a_{2}$$

However, we have full access to the distribution of $Y$ which we already know is a function of $\theta$, since $Y=X-\theta$. So, we can start by creating the confidence interval

$$\mathbb{P}(T_{1}\leq Y\leq T_{2})=1-a_{1}-a_{2}$$

For doing that we simply have to calculate the probabilities

$$\mathbb{P}(Y\leq T_{1})=a_{1}$$
and
$$\mathbb{P}(Y\geq T_{2})=a_{2}$$

since $\mathbb{P}(Y\geq T_{2})+\mathbb{P}(Y\leq T_{1})+\mathbb{P}(T_{1}\leq Y\leq T_{2}) = 1$.

We can do that with the distribution of the random variable $Y$

$$\mathbb{P}(Y\leq T_{1}) = 1 - \frac{1}{1+e^{T_{1}}} = a_{1}\Rightarrow \ldots \Rightarrow T_{1} = \log\left(\frac{a_{1}}{1-a_{1}}\right)$$

$$\mathbb{P}(Y\geq T_{2}) =  \frac{1}{1+e^{T_{2}}} = a_{2}\Rightarrow \ldots \Rightarrow T_{2} = \log\left(\frac{1-a_{2}}{a_{2}}\right)$$

So, we found the confidence interval for $Y$ such that $\mathbb{P}(T_{1}\leq Y\leq T_{2})=1-a_{1}-a_{2}$, however $Y$ is a function of $\theta$ so we can rewrite

$$\mathbb{P}(T_{1}\leq X-\theta \leq T_{2})=1-a_{1}-a_{2};$$
now rearranging the inequality we conclude that

$$\mathbb{P}(X-T_{2}\leq \theta \leq X-T_{1})=1-a_{1}-a_{2}.$$

Comment: thanks a lot for your help ! I was only wondering why you wrote 
$$\mathbb{P}(T_{1}\leq Y\leq T_{2})=1-a_{1}-a_{2}$$

For doing that we simply have to calculate the probabilities 

$$\mathbb{P}(Y\leq T_{1})=a_{1}$$
and 
$$\mathbb{P}(Y\geq T_{2})=a_{2}$$

instead of $$\mathbb{P}(Y\geq T_{1})=a_{1}$$
and 
$$\mathbb{P}(Y\leq T_{2})=a_{2}$$

Comment: maybe because $$\mathbb{P}(Y\geq T_{1}) = 1- a_{1} = \mathbb{P}(Y\leq T_{1}) =  a_{1}$$ and the same reason for $T_2$  Is my intuition correct?

Comment: @XY0 I wrote $\mathbb{P}(T_{1}\leq Y \leq T_{2})=1-a_{1}-a_{2}$, because you are looking for the $(1-a_{1}-a_{2})$ confidence interval of $\theta$. The reason for that is since $Y$ is a function of $\theta$ if I was calculating the confidence interval of $Y$ for lets's say  $\mathbb{P}(T_{1}\leq Y \leq T_{2})=b$ then how could I correspond it to a $(1-a_{1}-a_{2})$ confidence interval for $\theta$?

Answer (score 3):

The event* $$0 \in \left[Y-\log\left(\frac{1-\alpha_2}{\alpha_2}\right),Y-\log\left(\frac{\alpha_1}{1-\alpha_1}\right)\right]$$ is equivalent to the event $$\theta \in \left[X-\log\left(\frac{1-\alpha_2}{\alpha_2}\right),X-\log\left(\frac{\alpha_1}{1-\alpha_1}\right)\right]$$ so if you can show that that the first event occurs $1-\alpha_1-\alpha_2$ of the time, then it works as well for the second event. The advantage of working with the first event is that it doesn't depend anymore on the parameter $\theta$.

---

To compute the probability of the first event you might alternatively use the equivalent event

$$Y \in \left[\log\left(\frac{\alpha_1}{1-\alpha_1}\right),\log\left(\frac{1-\alpha_2}{\alpha_2}\right)\right]$$

Which follows from $a \leq Y \leq b$ then $a-Y \leq 0 \leq b-Y$ and $Y-b \leq 0 \leq Y-a$

Also useful to know is that the $f(x)$ in the question is the [logistic distribution](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_distribution) which has the quantile function $\log\left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)$ for the case with zero mean and scale one.

So the event is also the same as

$$Y \in \left[Q(\alpha_1),Q(1-\alpha_2)\right]$$

---

*I believe that you made a typo and should have used

$$\left[X-\log\left(\frac{1-\alpha_2}{\alpha_2}\right),X-\log\left(\frac{\alpha_1}{1-\alpha_1}\right)\right]$$

demonstration with R-code

```
set.seed(1)
x = rlogis(10^3)
alpha = 0.2
beta = 0.2

### correct boundaries contain
### zero in 602/1000 cases
upper = x-log(alpha/(1-alpha))
lower = x-log((1-beta)/beta)
mean((lower<0)*(upper>0))

### wrong boundaries contain
### zero in 664/1000 cases
upper = x-log(alpha/(1+alpha))
lower = x-log((1-beta)/beta)
mean((lower<0)*(upper>0))
```

Comment: hi , I didn't really get how to show the first event . I was trying to find the value of $y$ in order to construct the confidence interval , but I don't know how to do it $$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
F_Y(y) 
&= \mathbb{P}(0 \leqslant Y \leqslant y)= 1-\frac{1}{1+e^{y}}\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$  where $Y = X-\theta$. is this the correct approach?

Comment: You can compute the probability for the event $Y \in [a,b]$ with the CDF of $Y$.

Comment: sorry I am a bit confused . Can you please show how?

Comment: @XY0 for continuous variables we have $$P(Y \in [a,b]) = F_Y(b)-F_Y(a)$$